# JSON.stringify of an array returns a number after pushing more than one object

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to add products to the cart in my website with localStorage, so I initialize an array and then push products into it. The problem is when I use JSON.parse() to push a product and then stringify it again with JSON.stringify() it returns a number instead of the array. This is the part of my code that throws an error:

```js
let product = {
                id: i + 1,
                name: productNames[i].innerText,
                price: prices[i].innerHTML,
                img: imgs[i].src
            };

            if(localStorage.productsInCart) {
                let productsInLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("productsInCart") || "[]");
                console.log(productsInLocalStorage);
                let newArray = productsInLocalStorage.push(product);
                console.log(JSON.stringify(newArray));
                localStorage.productsInCart = JSON.stringify(newArray);
                numberOfProducts.innerHTML = parseInt(numberOfProducts.innerHTML, 10) + 1;

            } else {
                let productToStore = JSON.stringify([product]);
                localStorage.setItem("productsInCart", productToStore);
                numberOfProducts.style.display = "block";
                numberOfProducts.innerHTML = 1;
            };
```

And then in the console:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eifaP.png)

That circled 2 is the console.log() of the JSON.stringify. I have been searching for detailed info about this but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is this line:

`let newArray = productsInLocalStorage.push(product);`

From the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push): The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and **returns the new length of the array.** (emphasis mine)

You're assigning the length of the array to newArray.